# Locating text within a div's ul/li

Tags: jquery-selectors

using .NET MVC/Razor, I am working on setting the validation summary manually client side using the following method for a few js client side operations which will not be handled in data annotations:

```
 function RenderError(message) {

    var myDiv = $('[data-valmsg-summary="true"]');

    myDiv.removeClass("validation-summary-valid");
    myDiv.addClass("validation-summary-errors");

    var list = myDiv.find('ul');

    $("<li />").html(message).appendTo(list);
}
```

This works fine, but obviously repeats the errors. What is the simplest way to check and see if the message has already been entered in a list item? Keeping in mind that I already have a handle to the div itself?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could check in a if statement if the data-valmsg-summary field is true and skip it accordingly, does it make sense?